# Solving coupled recursion equations for a target variable

Tags: difference-equations

I have a set of coupled recursion equations and want to express the final solution in terms of one of the variables:

```
RSolve[
 {d[n] == a[n] + b[n] + c[n],
  a[n] == a[n - 1] + c[n - 1],
  b[n] == a[n - 1],
  c[n] == b[n - 1] + c[n - 1]},
 {d[n]}, n]
```

I know the result can be expressed as:

```
d[n] = d[n-1] + d[n-2] + d[n-4]
```

but *Mathematica* gives a variety of error messages, depending upon the variables.  (I get the error even if I include the following conditions:  `a[1] == a[2] == b[1] == b[2] == c[1] == c[2] == 0`.)  I've also included obvious equivalent conditions such as `d[n-1] = a[n-1]+b[n-1]+c[n-1]` and so on.

How can *Mathematica* solve these recursion relations and express the final answer solely in terms of `d[]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A general solution, making no assumptions about initial conditions, is as follows.  (The derivation proceeds much like the corresponding derivation for a set of first order ODEs.)  First, eliminate `b`.

```
eqs1 = {a[n] == a[n - 1] + c[n - 1], b[n] == a[n - 1], c[n] == b[n - 1] + c[n - 1]};
bsolv = Solve[d[n] == a[n] + b[n] + c[n], b[n]][[1, 1]];
eqs2 = eqs1 /. {bsolv, (bsolv /. n -> n - 1)};
eqs3 = Equal @@@ First@Solve[eqs2, {a[n], d[n], c[n]}];
(* {a[-1 + n] + c[-1 + n] == a[n], 
    a[-1 + n] + c[-1 + n] + d[-1 + n] == d[n], 
    a[-1 + n] + c[n] == d[-1 + n]} *)
```

Second, `Eliminate` `a` and `c`.

```
Eliminate[Join[{eqs3[[2]]}, (eqs3 /. n -> n - 1), (eqs3 /. n -> n - 2)], 
    {a[n - 1], a[n - 2], a[n - 3], c[n - 1], c[n - 2], c[n - 3]}];
ans = Equal @@ Solve[%, d[n]][[1, 1]]
(* d[n] == d[-3 + n] - d[-2 + n] + 2 d[-1 + n] *)
```

which is the result obtained by [Dr. Belisarius](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/193/dr-belisarius) by a different approach.  As expected, it is a third order difference equation.  The expression in the question is obtained by

```
Equal @@ Solve[(Subtract @@ ans) + (Subtract @@ ans /. n -> n - 1) == 0, d[n]][[1, 1]]
```

This difference equation is an order higher than necessary and, therefore, has a solution with four arbitrary constants instead of three.

**More compact derivation**

An alternative, more compact derivation can be achieved by treating all four equations in parallel.

```
{d[n] == a[n] + b[n] + c[n], a[n] == a[n - 1] + c[n - 1], 
    b[n] == a[n - 1], c[n] == b[n - 1] + c[n - 1]};

Equal @@@ First@Solve[%, {d[n], a[n], b[n], c[n]}];
Eliminate[Join[{First@%}, Flatten@Array[% /. n -> n - # &, 3]], 
    Flatten@Array[{a[n - #], b[n - #], c[n - #]} &, 4]];
Equal @@ Solve[%, d[n]][[1, 1]]

(* d[n] == d[-3 + n] - d[-2 + n] + 2 d[-1 + n] *)
```

Comment: thanks for a systematic/general  approach. +1 of course, :)

Comment: Of the several very helpful solutions (+1), I prefer this **More compact derivation** because it is compact and relies on `Solve` but not `FindSequenceFunction`.  (One could generate values of `d[i]` and use that function, as below, but it wouldn't be elegant.)  I thought that `RSolve` would be necessary (and spent much time exploring that), but apparently it is not necessary.  Thanks to all!

Answer (score 6):

I apologize if this is unhelpful (and it is not efficient):

```
m = {{1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}}
d[n_] := MatrixPower[m, n].{a, b, c}.{1, 1, 1}
df = FindSequenceFunction[d /@ Range[10]] /. {a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1};
```

yields a `DifferenceRoot`.

Testing one instance:

```
FullSimplify[d[n] - d[n - 1] - d[n - 2] - d[n - 4]]
```

yields 0.

Obviously, this is only 1 instance but perhaps it prompts better ideas.

Comment: I removed my comment, as it doesn't look helpful in perspective :) +1

Comment: @Dr.belisarius thanks...have re-edited :)

Answer (score 6):

Without setting initial conditions. Looking for linear recurrences:

```
rs = First@RSolve[{
      a[n] == a[n - 1] + c[n - 1],
      b[n] == a[n - 1],
      c[n] == b[n - 1] + c[n - 1],
      a[1] == a1, c[1] == c1, b[1] == b1}, {a@n, b@n, c@n},  n] ;

ss = Simplify[Table[a[n] + b[n] + c[n] /. rs, {n, 0, 9}] // N // Chop] // Chop;
ss1 = ss /. x_Real :> Round[x]
FindLinearRecurrence@ss1

(* {2, -1, 1} *)
```

So we found a different linear relationship than yours ;)

```
d[n] == 2 d[n-1] - d[n-2] +  d[n-3]
```

Comment: ,belisarius if you look at the `DifferenceRoot` in my silly answer it matches yours, it just happens to also be true that d[n-1]+d[n-3]=d[n-4] for this initial condition:)

Comment: @ubpdqn See update. I got rid of the initial conditions generalizing the result

Comment: very nice...a useful exercise which I will contemplate after some sleep, Btw I already voted. To paraphrase John 'Hannibal' Smith: 'I love it when a code does what I want to do'...the ramblings of sleep deprived 